# NodeJS - http.request and click on a link

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, httprequest

What do I need to add to this code to make 10% of the http requests also click a specific #link on the page. I am doing website conversion testing.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function() { }).listen(8124); // Prevent process shutting down

var requestNo = 1;
var maxRequests = 1000;

function requestTest() {
    http.request({ host: 'www.mywebsite.com', method: 'GET' }, function(res) {
        console.log('Completed ' + (requestNo++));

        if (requestNo <= maxRequests) {
            requestTest();
        }
    }).end();
}

requestTest();
```

Comment: Would that 10% need to be accurate? Or maybe could be a random.

Comment: Do you mean to just follow a link (e.g. make a request to another URL) or do you need to actually "run" the whole page, including Javascript and what not.

Comment: It would need to run the page including javascript for the tracking events to occur. For the 10% it can be random as long as its 10% of the total visits approximately.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to 'click on a link', you probably need a full headless browser (an implementation of web browser without user interface).

Examples include [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) and [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/)

Comment: So you mean that nodeJS cannot load the page and actually take actions without a headless browser?